# Why does my code return a bad access exception?

Tags: swift, exception, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access

I've got this swift sprite kit project that I am trying to work on, but whenever I run the game it crashes on the GameViewController at startup with a EXC_Bad_ACCESS CODE 1. Here is my code:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var imageBanner: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet var textBanner: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton?
@IBOutlet var shareButton: UIButton?
@IBOutlet var infoButton: UIButton?

var skView = SKView()
var scene = SKScene()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("View did load")
    skView = SKView(frame: self.view.frame)
    print("1")
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    print("2")
    skView.showsFPS = false
    print("3")
    skView.showsNodeCount = false
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    print("Done")
}
```

I guess it's worth noting that "Done" is logged in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a new `SKView`.
And why are you creating a scene variable initialized with a `SKScene()`  you never use?

Please just use the code Xcode generates for you for the `GameViewController`.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

  // more stuff here
}
```

Comment: It still crashes, and it was because I didn't want the scene to pop up as soon as the view loaded, I wanted it to pop up when a play button was clicked.